# WinRT C# ListView prevent drag and drop to a particular location

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, windows-runtime

I've got dragging and dropping working on my ListView, but I would like to prevent certain drags and certain drops based on location.

The first item (row 0) in my list should remain fixed. I don't want to allow them to drag it at all. I haven't figured out a way to prevent it from visibly being dragged, but at the very least I can stop them from dropping it by setting `item.AllowDrop = false;` as soon as they start dragging it.

1) How do I prevent the user from even being able to pick up that first item? How do I prevent just the first row from being Draggable?

Also, I want users to be able to pick up rows 1-n but I don't want them to be able to drop them before row 0. I want Row 0 to remain fixed in location as the first item. How do I prevent the user from picking up Row 3, for example, and then dragging it above Row 0 and dropping it?

Is it possible to redirect the drop location, so that if they try to drop it above Row 0 I can make it actually drop just below Row 0 (into the new Row 1 spot).

In iOS, I would be able to use something like

```
-tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to prevent the first row from moving, and I'd be able to use

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
```

to change the destination location for the drop from index 0 to index 1.

2) What is the proper Windows Runtime method of preventing drags and drops based on certain locations within the collection?

Answer (score 1):

(I hope you found a solution or workaround  since 2 years ago, but in case this helps anyone else that stumbles across this post...)

I had the same problem in Windows UWP. I didn't find a great solution, but as a workaround, I split the ListView's ItemsSource so that the first item that I want to remain fixed is separate. I also discovered that a ListViewItem doesn't necessarily have to be parented by a ListView. So my XAML looks something like this (pseudo code):

```
<MyFixedListViewItem
    Grid.Row="0">
    <!-- Bindings -->
</MyFixedListViewItem>

<ListView
    Grid.Row="1"
    CanReorderItems="True"
    CanDragItems="True"
    AllowDrop="True">
    <!-- DataTemplate and Bindings for everything else here -->
</ListView>
```